# Blank CiviCRM Home page after install

Tags: civicrm-home

This is my first time installing Civi. The install appeared to go OK but the Home and Configuration pages are blank.

The inspector shows these errors:

**Error: CRM.url called before initialization CRM.console @ Common.js?r=l6LAc:1617**

**Error: Cannot read property 'back' of undefined**

My error log shows:

**PHP Warning: include(/ebs2/vhosts/mvfn.ca/staging.mvfn.ca/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US//%%52/529/529A2042%%l10n.js.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /ebs2/vhosts/mvfn.ca/staging.mvfn.ca/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1273**

That file is indeed missing. The /templates_c/en_US/ directory exists but has only .htaccess in it. Permissions for that and all the other /uploads folders are 755, and the owner and group are the same for all.

Am I able to locate that file in the plugin ZIP and upload it manually? Any other ideas? Thanks.

I'm running WP 5.7.1.

**UPDATE**

Hi Aidan, thanks for your reply. I did follow that install procedure, yes, and the owner and group for that folder appear to be the same as for the rest of the server. In checking my logs I see a security warning at about the time I was doing the install -- some Googling suggests that this is a message from the Imunify security application. Sounds like I may have to try and sort this out with my hosting company.

**[client 174.89.56.82] ModSecurity: [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/custom/004_i360_4_custom.conf"] [line "905"] [id "77140992"] [msg "IM360 WAF: Suspicious access attempt (WP folders)!||SC:/var/www/vhosts/mvfn.ca/staging.mvfn.ca/wp-admin/options-general.php||T:APACHE||REQUEST_URI:/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install||"] [severity "NOTICE"] [tag "service_i360custom"] [tag "noshow"] Warning. Match of "pmFromFile path_excludes" against "REQUEST_FILENAME" required. [hostname "staging.mvfn.ca"] [uri "/wp-admin/options-general.php"]**

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SE!  Sorry to hear you are having problems installing CiviCRM.

Have you followed the installation instructions [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/wordpress/)?

Files are created automatically under the `templates_c` directory. The only thing you need to do there occasionally is to remove all the files.  (Normally that is taken care of by 'clearing the cache').

Is the file owner of the directory the same user as the one running your webserver?

Edit after the question update: yes, you'll need to talk to your hosting company about ModSecurity.